# How to get ttl along with the value for a key in redis/redisson

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am storing a Key and value in Redis using redisson java client .
Example as below

```
RMapCache<String, Integer> mapCache = redisson.getMapCache("test");

    // with ttl = 10 seconds
    Integer prevValue = mapCache.put("1", 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is there a way I can get the remaining ttl for the key when I do a get on the mapCahce ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can do that using `RKeys` and querying for the keys you are interested in

```
RKeys rkeys = redissonClient.getKeys();
long ttl = rkeys.remainTimeToLive(key);
```

It would be nice although to have a wrapper that exposes both the value and the ttl of a key